# Change Action bar color for different tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to use the new Android Lollipop support library. I set my primary color in my theme to set the color of the action bar. No i'm wondering if i can change this color at runtime. In my case it should change when another tab is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

Make a function and call this function when you change the tab

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat does not use the `android:` prefixed attributes for the [Material Theme color palette](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) items per the [migration guide to v21 by the author of AppCompat](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#migrationfromprevioussetup). Instead, just use the names themselves:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDef</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkDef</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryDef</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryDarkDef</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/defbg</item>
</style>
```

The Action Bar will be colored by `colorPrimary`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just found a nice pice of code, which also handles different version.
[changeColor](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java)